# SQL Server MAXDOP and TempDB Recommendations for VMs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, vmware, virtualisation

When configuring SQL Server on a VM does the recommendation around tempDb and MAXDOP still stand true?

TempDB - As a general rule, if the number of logical processors is less than or equal to 8, use the same number of data files as logical processors.

MAXDOP - Server with multiple NUMA nodes > Less than 8 logical processors > Keep MAXDOP at or below # of logical processors.

[Recommendations and guidelines for the "max degree of parallelism" configuration option in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2806535/recommendations-and-guidelines-for-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-confi)

I have a VM with the following and 2016 SP1 installed so my intention is to config 2 TempDb files and set MAXDOP = 2?

[image]

Comment: When you install SQL Server 2016+, tempdb should be automatically configured for you during setup according to the best practices you referenced. Was it not, or have you not installed it yet?

Comment: Not installed yet. So the fact it's a VM doesn't make any difference? Is the same true for MAXDOP?

Comment: No, but if you _really_ cared you wouldn't be running on those six year old Opterons. Heh.

Comment: I blame the VMWare admin for that! :-) Thanks for clarify this.

Comment: You should consider Cost Threshold for parallelism and MaxDop. Best practices are : Threshold 25 or 50 (depends of queries) and MaxDop : number of logical CPU cores divide by 2. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/five-sql-server-settings-to-change/

Comment: @liotims thanks, but in this case that would mean a MAXDOP of 1 which would mean the server is singled threaded and also goes against a post by Erik [Configuring Parallelism Confusion](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/configuring-parallelism/) which says MAXDOP in general shouldn't = 1 and shouldn't be set to an odd number.